# \cmidrule stopping Latex compiling/compiler loop with no error

Tags: tables

My document suddenly stopped compiling. It appeared to be in an endless loop. No errors are given.

After debugging I found that the problem was in a `tabular` environment. Specifically with the line `\cmidrule`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Data.}
    \begin{tabular}{c S S S S}
    \toprule
    Case & {$A$} & $B$ & $C$ & {$D$} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{Sub-case 1} \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \cmidrule
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{Sub-case 2} \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Where and what is the problem and how do I address it?

Comment: You should at least add a small sample document replicating the problem, otherwise I don't think the question and answer won't be of much help for others

Comment: This posting, as it stands, is rather unlikely to ever be of any use to future readers. Instead of making extremely broad statements such as "the problem was in a `tabular` environment", it would be much more useful for future readers *where* in the `tabular` environment the crash occurs.

Comment: FWIW, I get a single error: "Runaway argument?
\multicolumn ]{\cmidrulewidth }{}{5}{l}{Sub-case 2} \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@@@cmidrule."  But TeX won't continue on through the rest of the document.

Comment: @Teepeemm interesting. I am compiling with pdfLaTeX via the Overleaf online platform. Also tried within Texmaker.

Comment: Overleaf can sometimes make it difficult [to find the errors](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7898/107497).  I assume that it attempts to compile the entire file, and then show you any syntax errors.  With most syntax errors, TeX is able to recover enough to at least keep checking the syntax.  But this error isn't letting you continue on.  I'm not sure about TeXMaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spanning of the `\cmidrule` was causing the problems. The column limits for the `\cmidrule` had not been explicitly set. The rule was desired across the whole table so it was left blank.

After setting the limits with `\cmidrule{a-b}` the document compiled correctly. The solution is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Data.}
    \begin{tabular}{c S S S S}
    \toprule
    Case & {$A$} & $B$ & $C$ & {$D$} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{Sub-case 1} \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \cmidrule{1-5}
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{Sub-case 2} \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a MWE that explains the problem. As it is, this answer does not help users that much.

Comment: You wrote, "the rule was desired across the whole table". In that case, you might want to write `\midrule[\cmidrulewidth]`.

Comment: @cyuut: Of course, the use of `usepackage{tabular}` in the preamble is completely useless and would cause errors as well.

Comment: @cyuut: Don't just change `usepackage{tabular}` to `\usepackage{tabular}`... There is no package called `tabular` by default, unless you have a local package named `tabular.sty`. All you would need is `\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}` for your example, but test this first.

Comment: @Werner ops ha yes. I was getting my `booktabs` and `tabularx` all mixed up. Tested as updated.